# Entity framework single query insert child entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am learning about Entity Framework (EF) using code first on version 6+ with C# POCOs. Consider the following example:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    public virtual DbSet<TextElement> Textuals { get; set; }
}

public class TextElement
{
    [Key]
    public int                              Number   { get; set; }
    public string                           Content  { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TextElement> Children { get; set; }
}
```

What I want to do is to add a new child to an existing parent. in pseudo SQL I could do something like:

```
INSERT INTO Textuals (Content, ParentId) VALUES ("Lorem Ipsum", 42)
```

Where 42 is the ID of the parent record.

I've been searching the web for the past day to get EF to do the same for me in C# code. The best I could find is:

```
using (var context = new  DatabaseContext())
{
    var parent = new TextElement { Number = 42, Children = new List<TextElement>() };
    var child  = new TextElement { Content = "I iz kiddo" };
    context.Textuals.Attach(parent);
    parent.Children.Add(child);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

However, the `Attach` call seems to run a query too. The same issue applies to deleting an entity by id, that needs an `Attach` as well, running an unnecessary query.

Is there a better performing alternative to do what I want: add a child entity to an existing parent?

**Update**

Based on cverb's answer I got the following code doing what I want:

```
public class TextElement
{
    [Key]
    public int                              Number   { get; set; }
    public string                           Content  { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TextElement> Children { get; set; }
    // Added custom parent id reference, MUST be nullable to allow 
    // for entries without parent
    public int?                             ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Now, because this is a name that breaks convention (convention dictates `TextElementId` which is as vague as can be) I needed to change the Context with a little "fluent api" code. This explicitly defines the relations between the properties in the class.

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<TextElement>()
            .HasMany((e) => e.Children)        // Indicate the many relation
            .WithOptional()                    // Indicate that the many
                                               // relation is optional.
                                               // Don't require a nav prop
            .HasForeignKey((e) => e.ParentId); // The FK to use with the
                                               // relation.
    }

    public virtual DbSet<TextElement> Textuals { get; set; }
}
```

Which enables me to successfully apply Migrations as well.

Comment: Do you have a `ParentId`property in your TextElement entity?

Comment: Only indirectly with the `Children` property. I obviously like EF to handle the implementation details =). But without performance overhead if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the `ParentId` explicitly on your `TextElement` entity.

```
public int? ParentId { get; set; }
```

If you don't know how to do that, there is some good information on [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) under section "Understanding Convention for One to Many Relationships".

And then you can add a new entity by just using the following code.

```
using (var context = new  DatabaseContext())
{
    var child  = new TextElement { Content = "I iz kiddo", ParentId = 42 };
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

No need for attaching or adding the child to the parent's `Children`-list, because Entity Framework will pick up the change itself.

Comment: Thanks for the hint and reference. I'll have a go at that! It's unfortunate that the implementation details need to be in the models as well but I guess I'll have to make do. I'll accept if it fits the bill!

Answer (score 0):

the way that you are using is the correct way... here, the EF context do all the job for you: start a transaction do the inserts edits and deletes needed, and finally commit the changes.

Comment: So you're basically saying that I should just accept 100% overhead on my queries in this case? I only need one query to insert a new record but I can't make the association to the parent node without running an additional query?

Answer (score 0):

Going by this

> What I want to do is to add a new child to an existing parent

and this sql script you used

> INSERT INTO Textuals (Content, ParentId) VALUES ("Lorem Ipsum", 42)

here is what should work for you.

```
using (var context = new  DatabaseContext())
{
    var newTextual  = new Textuals { Number = 42, Content = "I iz kiddo" };
    context.Textuals.Attach(newTextual);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Please read my question. This would just overwrite the existing parent's content with the child's content. Note that there are (at least) three columns: Number, Content and 'ParentID'. The latter being the column that EF generates for that association. In the database it actually looks like: `TextElement_Number`. That would make you solution: `var newTextual  = new Textuals { TextElement_Number= 42, Content = "I iz kiddo" };` where it not that I can't directly access `TextElement_Number`.